# Android using Google account but without user interaction

Tags: java, android

I try to develop parental control app and in setup page the parent enters his email to receive location of his kids.

when use JavaMail API using Gmail authentication, need password and email to send email to the parent (and it is not professional way to ask user email and password of his email).

And cannot be used `intent` because need without user interaction.

So Can anyone Help me or gives me and suggestions

**I suggest send emails to user using Google account but without user interaction *- If possible-***